# How to run release build of React native IOS app?

Tags: react-native

I have create the release build of React Native IOS app. It create .app file in my project. Next how I can run this file in a physical IOS device?

I also tried to create its ipa from below method. Please tell if its wrong

1. Create a folder named Payload
2. Place .app  file inside payload folder and zip it.
3. Change the extension of payload folder to .ipa

I tried this and uploaded ipa to diawi.com but got this error

> invalid ipa file missing embedded mobileprovision

How to resolve it ?